# SharePoint CAML query Where clause Not Filtering

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, caml

I am trying to construct a CAML query for list item on SP2019 site. I have the below code returning the entire list. I read that if there is a issue in the query , all the items in the list are returned. Please advise.

```
            List dashboardList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Dashboard");
            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            string searchfor = "CPPMC";
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Title'/><Value Type ='Text'>" + searchfor+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query>";
            ListItemCollection listItems = dashboardList.GetItems(camlQuery);
            context.Load(listItems);
            context.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (ListItem item in listItems)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0},{1},{2}",item.Id,item["Title"], item["Processing_x0020_Date"]);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried -

```
camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name = 'Title'/><Value Type ='Text'>" + searchfor+ "</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

Note - use scope = RecursiveAll if you have folders in the list/library